# How to destroy a session for username and password to prevent second login?

Tags: php, mysql, session, post, get

Am trying to create an e-voting system which the user will login to the candidates page where to vote for the candidate, and i want the username to vote once after clicking the vote button it should destroy or end the session to prevent another login.

Comment: If they have to login to vote, then surely you should just set a flag against their login record to say they have already voted

Answer (score 1):

when you are done with adding vote to the database once immediately after that

try [session destory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) and then [redirect to login page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

If user again login and try to add vote you need to check first with running query like this

**select * form vote where user_id=$_SESSIOn['user_id']**

into DB that weather this user has already voted or not as @Mark Baker already told.

```
$is_voted = true or false;
if($is_voted) {
   //your voting code..
} else {
   echo "You have already voted"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, What if the user login back with his or her username and password again?

Comment: @Ibrahim think for your requirements as per Mark Baker told you in comment. i update ans with query here,

Answer (score 0):

to destroy a session within your php just do: `session_destroy();` but this will propably force him to logout (depends of your login implementation)

to check if a session variable exist do:

`if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
exit ("authentication error");
}`

thought as @Mark Baker sais for your voting action it is better to follow his advise

Answer (score 0):

try session destroy

`session_destroy();`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you all, have done it. Check my code below.

initial.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['status'] != 'NO') { // if         session variable "username" does not exist.
header("location: index.php?        msg=Please%20login%20to%20access%20admin%20area%20!&type=error"); // Re-         direct to index.php - which means it doesn't meet the 
}
?>
```

If the variable "status" is equals to "NO" means the user haven't logged in before.

If the variable "status" is equals to "YES" means the user have logged in before.

checklogin.php

```
<?php
$sql = "UPDATE voters SET status='YES' WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result= mysqli_query($db->connection, $sql);
?>
```

Once the user logged in its update the variable "status" to "YES" , whenever the same user try to log in again it won't accept it.